# Installing python2.6 and assorted libraries on DreamHost

Tags: python, lxml, dreamhost

I managed to install python2.6 on DreamHost following [this](http://www.reverttoconsole.com/blog/django/dreamhost-django-install-revised-edition/) guide. I also tried to easy_install "lxml" but it fails horribly.

Anyone ever accomplished this?

TIA

Comment: Really this should be on ServerFault. That aside, it'd be useful to post a lot more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django and http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Building_a_custom_version_of_Python - it contains the most up to date info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not what I'm having trouble with. I already installed my custom version of Python and the corresponding version of setuptools (easy_install). What I can't do is install lxml. Apparently, the servers at DreamHost don't have the development libs to compile etree.

Comment: In this case you'd have to try recompiling all required dependencies yourself manually. The list of dependencies can be seen on http://packages.debian.org/lenny/python-lxml

Comment: Links are unfortunately broken.

Comment: @maugch DreamHost took down the wiki. Maybe https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dreamhost is the better way to ask the question after these 9 years if Python2.6 is still actual.